# Controls bound to table with diffrent row layouts

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, wpf-controls, database-table

So i have this scenario where i have a database table that can contain values of diffrent types.
Most of the values will be static text from another table, but a few rows will contain a "freetext" value.
The problem i have is trying to make a layout for this in wpf.

What i want is somthing like this mockup:

[image: Layout-mockup]

Tables looks something like this:

[image: The tables]

So basicly first value is type of value i want to store in the table.
And this value should also determine what the row looks like in the interface.

Can't find a good approach for this, any suggestions?

Comment: You can use templateselector when you bind but I don't think you can dynamically change the template.

Comment: Ill look into it, but you are probably right.